# Spring XD http-client processor sends text/plain instead of application/json

Tags: json, spring-xd

I am trying to create a stream that sends a POST request as part of a stream.

```
stream create form-time --definition "<working source> | generate-form-transformer: transform --script=form-generation.groovy  --outputType=application/json | http-client --inputType=application/json ..." --deploy
```

It works, but it sets contentType to text/plain instead of application/json, which provokes a 400 since my server does not support that. (The content is perfect JSON though).

The transformer returns a XD Tuple, so as far as I understood conversion from Tuple to JSON should be done properly (in fact, as pointed out previously, the payload is correct).

However, when it comes to http-client it does not fix **contentType** being `text/plain;UTF-8` instead of `application/json`.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the `--inputType` and `--outputType` conversions are supposed to set a header, they just perform the conversion; one technique would be to add a header enricher to the `http-client`...

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/modules/processor/http-client/config/http-client.xml b/modules/processor/http-client/config/http-client.xml
index cf7d2e2..c2ecd00 100644
--- a/modules/processor/http-client/config/http-client.xml
+++ b/modules/processor/http-client/config/http-client.xml
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

        <int-http:outbound-gateway id='http-client'
-               request-channel='input' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
+               request-channel='inputX' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
                expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'
                mapped-request-headers="${mappedRequestHeaders}"
@@ -19,5 +19,9 @@

        <channel id="output" />
        <channel id="input" />
+       <channel id="inputX" />
+       <header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="inputX">
+               <header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
+       </header-enricher>
```

There is now a header-enricher processor module in spring-xd-modules.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary. As you pointed out, I was pretty confident about inputType, outputType not being the issue here. I was indeed looking for a header-enricher, and I ended up writing a groovy script since there is nothing in documentation. Would you be so kind to point me out where the doc for that header enricher is, and for which version it may apply (I'm using last stable release). I actually looked in jira and there is a non-closed epic for that, so I assumed such a thing is non existing yet.


I'm going to try to set up content type through headers, and if it works I'll come back.

Comment: Thanks gary, you were completely right. Setting the header solved the issue. Nonetheless I did that through groovy since I didn't find that module. Don't you think it may be wise to set up that header for http-client when content in payload is json (i was thinking about rising a ticket, since it looks as a reasonable default to me).

Comment: It was recently added to the [spring-xd-modules repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/header-enricher). It uses Groovy to add a variable number of headers. It is for Spring XD 1.2 (which will be available very shortly - the release candidate was [announced last week](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/02/spring-xd-1-2-rc1-released). I do think there should be an option to set the header when using in/outputType; feel free to open a JIRA issue to request it.

Answer (score 0):

> stream create form-time --definition " | generate-form-transformer: transform --script=form-generation.groovy  --outputType=application/json | http-client --inputType=application/json ..." --deploy

Did you set `--outputType=application/json` for the `http-client` module. Also, the `--inputType` in `http-client` isn't necessary as the output type of the previous module is already `application\json`. Probably, you intend to set that as `--outputType`?